# Add custom block on listing page : Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-list

I want to add my custom block on listing page[Magento-2] **but without any modification on `list.phtml` or any `.phtml`** file. Is there any possibility by using `xml` file  ?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Great article. Would you expand more detail on test.phtml to override the orginal listing page? As I'm a new comer on Magento 2.

Comment: How can I get use the function getProductDetailsHtml() for add block 'label' NEW on grid in test.phtml?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that if you create new module to override this block: `vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php`

to override this block, you need to create `di.xml` at `app\code\Vendor\Module_Name\etc`

`di.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

Create new file name `ListProduct.php` at `app\code\Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product`

`ListProduct.php` content:

```
namespace Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product;
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Vendor_ModuleName::test.phtml')->toHtml();
        $renderer = $this->getDetailsRenderer($product->getTypeId());
        if ($renderer) {
            $renderer->setProduct($product);
            return $html.$renderer->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

You can change block `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` to your block

create `test.phtml` file at `app\code\Vendor\Module_Name\view\frontend\templates`

Comment: Thanks for the information +1 from me... But can we achieve without override  ?

Comment: @KeyurShah, is above the best method so far in Mage 2.0 to add your custom block on listing page ? I also agree with Kandy as product output is hardcoded in list.phtml.

Comment: @Vikram till now, I think this is the best method so far and is also working fine for me..

Comment: @KeyurShah, I have already overriddien that with `di.xml` using above method. Now how to display my custom attribute value in listing page ?

Comment: @Vikram you can use Mageev2 code to display your custom attribute. I mean in test.phtml you can get $product object and from $product object you can get easily its attribute value.

Comment: I have written in my phtml like <?php $product=$this->getProduct(); ?> <span><?php echo $product->getMycustomValue();?></span>, Rest Magev2 code do the magic

Comment: This seems to work great, but only on actual catalog pages, if I have products listed on other pages (like front page), it does not work. Any advice how to apply it to product listings everywhere?

Comment: not working for me!

Comment: Genius i really like this no functions however i can use to pull this further up the product listing however.

Comment: @magev2 can you  please explain when module disable from Disable Modules Output what happen?. its break my category page because in solution template are added in block and Disable Modules Output not disable module its just disable module output content.

Comment: so how can i stop the block override when module output are disable

Comment: my test.phtml is not shwoing ,but ListProduct.php is called, is there any thing that i  am missing?

Answer (score 4):

Currently you cannot do this because all logic of product output is hardcoded in `list.phtml` template.

Comment: Yeah I know that,,But is there any hook or any trick available for that ? Btw, Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on the solution - but you must modify the `list.phtml` template:

`catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="custom.block.container" as="custom-block-container">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Block" name="custom.block" as="custom-block"
           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom-block.phtml" />
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

In `custom-block.phtml` you can get the product like this:

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

You will need to overwrite the `list.phtml` template though... Just add this where you want your custom block to show:

```
<?php if ($customBlock = $block->getChildBlock('custom-block-container')): ?>
    <?= $customBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you *really* want to avoid modifying the `list.phtml` template, then you might be able to do a similar thing but in a different template.