# Is it possible to add a block at the middle of the products listing , in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, products

I'm using Magento 2 , and I would like to add a block at the middle of the products listing , on the category page , I've tryed to add the block in the Main Content Container , but it puts the block at the bottom of the listing..

Comment: you can refer to following question - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96642/add-custom-block-on-listing-page-magento2

Comment: at which place you want to add block, give destination

Comment: Lets say I have 12 products on my page , 3 on each row , I want a block with a message after 6 products , and after the block the products continue..

Comment: I solved this by setting Used for Sorting in Product Listing to No , thank you for your time @Rakesh , I'm still looking for a solution to this though  : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113121/is-it-possible-to-add-a-block-at-the-middle-of-the-products-listing-in-magento?noredirect=1#comment153680_113121    have you got any ideea ?