# Magento 2 : How can I call helper function on override product list block

Tags: magento2

I want to show some extra data on product list page so I override the vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php . For this I refer [Add custom block on listing page : Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96642/add-custom-block-on-listing-page-magento2). It work.

But I need to call my helper function in my override block file. Created new file name ListProduct.php in app\code\Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product

```
namespace Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product;
 class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 {

  // I need to call my module helper function here:

   public function test(){

   }
 }
```

How can I call my helper function inside this block file. Thanks

Comment: plz show your helper file path so i can tell about it

Comment: My helper path is, app\code\Vendor\Mymodule\Helper\Data.php 

      namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Helper;
       class Data extends       \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
       {
           public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
          \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface     $scopeConfig
    ) {
  
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
      public function test(){
       return "test";
     }

      }

I need to call test function on my block

Comment: plz show your helper path.

Comment: you have to extend helper function in your list.php file, right?

Comment: Please find my updated edit.

Comment: I don't know how to extend my helper function on list.php

Comment: Its work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can call your helper function as per below,

```
 namespace Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product;
     class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
     {
           public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,        
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
            \Vendor\Mymodule\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;       
            parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $postDataHelper,
                $layerResolver,
                $categoryRepository,
                $urlHelper,
                $data
            );
        }

       public function test(){
            $this->dataHelper->getHelperFunction();
       }
    }
```

Remove `var` folder and refresh again.

Comment: It helped got some bug on var/generation/vendor\mymodule\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor.php. So I deleted that folder and flushed cache again I refreshed the page then the bug rectified.

Comment: you have to remove var folder first and try again

Comment: Shall we delete the whole var folder?
won't it create any issues
I just flushed the cache alone, php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: no you have to just delete whole var folder, all files are generated automatically when you can refresh page

Answer (score 2):

You will have to overwrite the constructor of the parent class and add your extra class instance on to it something like:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data as UrlHelper;
use Vendor\Mymodule\Helper\Data as Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct as MagentoListProduct

class ListProduct extends MagentoListProduct
{
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Helper $customHelper
        Context $context,
        PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        UrlHelper $urlHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->customHelper = $customHelper;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data
        );
    }


    public function test()
    {
        $this->customHelper->yourCustomMethod();
    }
}
```

But if its only the helper you would like to use in the PHTML file **you need not overwrite the ListProduct** block you can use the following method as well.

First you can overwrite the template file using an custom theme.

In the new file you can get a instance of you helper using:

```
$customHelper = $this->helper('Vendor\Mymodule\Helper\Data');
```

And ofcourse you would need to clear the **var** folder either by

```
rm -rf ./var/*
```

or you can do it by

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, even if I used the use the class names inside constructor instead of defining before it works.
In order to avoid the large code I used the class inside the constructor itself.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me.  I had used this Simple Answer. $customHelper = $this->helper('Vendor\Mymodule\Helper\Data');   :)

Answer (score 2):

Ugly way will be:

```
     namespace Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product;
     class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
     {
       public function test(){
           $dataHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get("\Vendor\Mymodule\Helper\Data");
           // Do some stuff with $dataHelper
       }
     }
```

It will be better in case you need test some things quickly.