# Overwrite magento2 function using plugin method?

Tags: magento2, plugin

I want to customize return value of  `$block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product)` (in `list.phtml`) using plugin method, not overrite `list.phtml`

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Block `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` extends `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`. `AbstractProduct` have `getProductDetailsHtml($_product)` so you need to add plugin for `AbstractProduct`

**Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

        <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
            <plugin name="vendor.module.category.products.list" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Product\AbstractProduct" />
        </type>

    </config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Product;

    class AbstractProduct
    {
        public function afterGetProductDetailsHtml(
            \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
            $result
        ) {
             // $result contains the original values
             // do the stuff to change $results 
             // easy for your reference I just pass below string
             return '<b>test</b>';
        }
    }
```

**Note:** We can use `after`, `before`, `around` so you need to decide which is the best suite for you. Refer this [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html) for how to use.

I have checked, it works

[image: easy for your reference]

Comment: `di.xml` should be under: `Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml`

Comment: yep you right @KhoaTruongDinh, I'll update

Comment: is this still working, i have tried with 2.2.3.But does not working.

Answer (score 1):

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="block-product-list" type="Vender\Module\Plugin\ProductList"/>
</type>
```

> Vendor/Module/Plugin/ListProduct.php

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Plugin;

class ProductList
{   

    public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($product);          
        return $result . 'Add DetailsHtml code here';       
    }               
}
```